# Lipschitz continuity of $t|x|^a$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity, lipschitz-functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with $(t,x)\mapsto t|x|^{a}$ be given. Let $a\in[0,\infty)$.

1. Prove that for $a=1$ $f$ is not Lipschitz continuous (wrt 2nd argument)
2. Find $a$ for which $f$ is Lipschitz continuous (wrt 2nd argument)
3. Find $a$ for which $f$ is locally Lipschitz continuous (wrt 2nd argument)

My answers so far:

1. Let $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ be arbitrary. Then the following holds by the reversed triangle inequality:
   $|f(t,y)-f(t,x)|=|\,t|y|-t|x|\,|\leq |t|\,|y-x|\overset{t\rightarrow\infty}{\longrightarrow}\infty$. So there is no constant $K>0$ such that for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $|f(t,y)-f(t,x)|=|\,t|y|-t|x|\,|\leq\,K|y-x|$. We thus conclude that $f$ is not Lipschitz continuous.
2. The only choice is $a=0$. Then $f$ is linear and thus Lipschitz continuous with constant $K=2$ for example.
3. I think that $a\geq\,1$ gives a locally Lipschitz continuous function. For $a<1$ we get a problem at $x=0$.

My questions:

1. Is this proof correct?
2. Is it correct that this is the only choice?
3. Is my choice correct? And how can I prove my choice?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are thinking of uniform Lipschitz continuity w.r.t. $x$ (uniform w.r.t. $t$) but you just say Lipschitz continuity w.r.t. $x$. There is a difference between the two.

Comment: All your answers are correct if the Lipschitz constant is required to be independent of $t \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thank you. The exercise does not say uniform Lipschitz, but yes, this is meant. The Lipschitz constant has to be independent of t. Can you help me proving nr. 3?